# Javascript issue using .setFilter and Mapbox API

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox

I'm using Mapbox's API to load markers on a map, and I want different markers to appear depending on whether the checkbox corresponding to their marker color is checked.

My data.geoJSON file looks something like this:

```
{ 
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [ { 
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": { 
      "type": "Point", 
      "coordinates": [13.353323936462402, 38.11200434622822]
    },
    "properties": {
      "marker-color": "#9c89cc", 
      "marker-color": "#3b5998"
    }
  } ]
}
```

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id='filters' class='ui-select'>
  <input type='checkbox' checked=checked class='filter' name='filter' id='blue' value='blue'/>
  <label for='blue'>
    Blue marker checkbox
  </label>
</div>

<div id='map'></div>
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to get a `.change()` function to work *inside* `.setFilter( function(feature) {} )`.

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
  .loadURL('/map/getjson/')
  .addTo(map)
  .setFilter(
    function (feature) {
      //$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
        if ($("#blue").prop("checked")) {
          return (feature.properties["marker-color"] === "#3b5998");
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      //});
    }
  );
```

Basically, if `return(feature.properties["marker-color"] === "#3b5998")` evaluates to `true`, the marker with the indicated set of features will be display. Otherwise, the markers won't display.

[This](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/multiple-marker-filters/) is some example javascript that Mapbox gives (no use of jQuery).

```
map.featureLayer.setFilter(function(feature) {
  return (feature.properties['marker-symbol'] in enabled);
}
```

But I'm stumped about how to use `.change()` or `.click()` here, since I want the markers to display depending on whether or not their corresponding checkbox is checked.

I tried using .click():

```
function (feature) {
  //$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
    if ($("#blue").prop("checked")) {
      return (feature.properties["marker-color"] === "#3b5998");
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  //});
}
```

... but it doesn't work! I guess I can't use `.click()` inside this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so to review the time-dimension:

- Calling `setFilter()` will set the filter of markers immediately.
- jQuery's `.click()` will fire when someone clicks.

So the idea of using `click()` inside of setFilter is backwards. Do the opposite:

```
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer()
  .loadURL('/map/getjson/')
  .addTo(map)
  // initially set the filter
  .setFilter(showBlueIfChecked);

$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function() {
  // refilter items when people click the checkbox
  featureLayer.setFilter(showBlueIfChecked);
});

function showBlueIfChecked(feature) {
  if ($("#blue").prop("checked")) {
    return (feature.properties["marker-color"] === "#3b5998");
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the event handler try this

```
function (feature){
    $('.filter').on('change', function(){
        alert($(this).val() + " has changed"); //You can remove this line after testing
        //do stuff to map
    })
}
```

Assuming all the check boxes have the `class="filter"`

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/368TC/)